# Derivative of $f(A) = \|A x\|^2$ with respect to the Matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Suppose I have $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $A$ is interpreted as a matrix. We can define $f(A) = ||A x||^2$ for some constant $x$.

What is the derivative of $f$, written as matrix?

I have tried flattening out the matrix and using usual vector calculus and I got $f'(A)_{i j} = 2 x_i e_j^T A x$ where $e_j$ is the $j$th standard basis vector.

Is this correct? Is there a faster way to do this? Can the answer be written as a matrix expression?

Comment: You may be able to use some of the identities in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities

Comment: I think you have the $i,j$ switched above?

Comment: I think I fixed it

Comment: I mean you should have $2 x_j e_i^T A x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x) = \|x\|^2$, then by looking at the linear terms of $h$ in $g(x+h)-g(x)$, we see that $Dg(x)(h) = 2 x^T h$.

If we let $L(A) = Ax$, we see that since $L$ is linear that we have
$DL(A)(H) = Hx$.

Using the composition rule, we have
$Df(A)(H)=D(g \circ L)(A)(H) = Dg(L(A))DL(A)(H)$, and expanding this gives
$Df(A)(H) = 2 (Ax)^T Hx = 2 x^T A^THx$.

Just to clarify, that is the map $H \mapsto 2 x^T A^THx$.

To check, the partial derivative with respect to $[A]_{ij}$ is
$Df(A)(e_i e_j^T) = 2x^T A^Te_i e_j^Tx = 2 x_j e_i^T Ax$.

Comment: Saw this just as I was about to finish writing my solution! Thanks. You can also put the solution as a matrix

Comment: @Mark: You need to be careful with this, you can compute a gradient matrix (with respect to the Frobenius norm), but you can't express the derivative operator in the form of matrix multiplication.

Comment: Haven't heard of gradient matrix, but in the sense that I have it, the i,jth entry of my answer is the derivative of f with respect to the i,jth entry of the original matrix. You are right that the operator is not a matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to derive this after looking at related stack exchange questions.

$$f(A) = x^T A^T A x$$
$$f(A+\Delta) = f(A) + x^T A^T \Delta x + (x^T A^T \Delta x)^T + o(||\Delta||^2)$$

Therefore the derivative is the linear term

$$\Delta \mapsto x^T A^T \Delta x + (x^T A^T \Delta x)^T = 2 x^T A^T \Delta x$$  (since the result is one dimensional, the term and its transpose are equal)

Setting $\Delta = \delta_{i,j}$ we can put the result in component form
$$ 2 x^T A^T \delta_{i,j} x = 2 x^T A^T x_i e_j = 2(e_j^T Ax)^Tx_i$$
$$ = (2 A x x^T)_{i,j} $$

So in matrix form the derivative is $f'(A) = 2 A x x^T$

Comment: The expression you have for $f'(A)$ is the gradient (with respect to the Frobenius norm). The (Frechet) derivative is given by the linear operator $f'(A)(H) = 2 x^T A^T Hx$, which cannot be written as a matrix times $H$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$ f'(A)(H)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(A+tH)-f(A)}{t}. $$
Easy calculation shows that
$$ f'(A)(H)=2x^TA^THx $$
from which you can get $f'(A)$.